# Batch parsing with newline and then colon as delimiter

Tags: batch-file, confluence

I want to parse the result of a command in a windows batch file. I'm using [confluence-cli](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ACLI/pages/60194830/Action+Reference).

The command `cmd.exe /c confluence.bat --action getPage --title 'My title' --space XXX` returns a result similar to this one:

```
Data for page with id: 123456789

Page id . . . . . . . . . . . : 123456789
Title . . . . . . . . . . . . : My title
Space key . . . . . . . . . . : XXX
Space name  . . . . . . . . . : XXX
Space home page id  . . . . . : 987654321
Space home page title . . . . : XXX
Parent id . . . . . . . . . . : 987654321
Parent title  . . . . . . . . : My parent title
Creator . . . . . . . . . . . : user1
Created . . . . . . . . . . . : 11/09/18 10:10
Modifier  . . . . . . . . . . : user1
Modified  . . . . . . . . . . : 11/09/18 10:14
Version . . . . . . . . . . . : 1
Version message . . . . . . . :
Content type  . . . . . . . . : page
Status  . . . . . . . . . . . : current
Is home page  . . . . . . . . : No
URL . . . . . . . . . . . . . : https://XXX.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/XXX/pages/123456789
```

I want to get either the Page id field (`123456789`), or either the URL field (`https://XXX.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/XXX/pages/123456789`).
I've tried a command similar to this one, but have had no luck so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set getPage="cmd.exe /c confluence.bat --action getPage --title 'My title' --space XXX"
FOR /f "eol=#tokens=0delims=:2" %%a IN ('%getPage% /i0 %1 ^|find "id: "') DO SET /a pageId=%%a
ECHO Page id is %pageId%
GOTO :EOF
```

I'm having trouble manipulating the for expression in bat to achieve what I want, especially with the `token` and `delim` expression.

Comment: why there are no spaces in your for loop options? Though I thing setting `2` as delimiter is wrong as it will split the line by `2` too which can be part of the id. You rather need the second token -> `"tokens=2 delims=:"`

Comment: Is the line containing the 'id' always the first?

Comment: Yes it's always the first line. It's what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: The search string in the find command is incorrect. There is no colon after id.

Comment: you don't need `eol`, there is no zeroth token (they start with 1, you want the second after the delimiter `:`. Your `delims=:2` delimits at each `:` and on each `2` (probably not what you want). Use just `tokens=2 delims=:"`. Note: this captures the space too, which you can strip with another `for` or with `set "pageid=%pageid:~1%"` (strip the first character, which is the space)